# Translating pseudo-code from C to MIPS

Tags: c, assembly, mips, pseudocode, translate

I am currently learning MIPS which is challenging. I have been assigned some questions which ask to translate pseudo-code written in the C language to MIPS.

- One question is `sp = sp - 16`. After some research I believe `sp` is stack pointer in C. The answer I came up with was, `sub $sp, $sp, 16.` Are there any additional steps with `sp` or am I simply subtracting 16 from `$sp` and storing the new value back in `$sp?`
- Another question asks: `t0 = 2147483647 - 2147483648`. My answer is `subu $t0, 2147483647, 2147483648`. If I don't use subtract unsigned I will get an exception, is my train of thought on the right path here. Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: "pseudo-code written in the C language"...

Comment: _"My answer is `subu $t0, 2147483647, 2147483648`"_. There's no form of `subu` that takes two immediate operands. But since `2147483647 - 2147483648` can be evaluated at compile-time (the result is `-1`) you could implement it as `addiu $t0,$zero,-1`.

Comment: if you write the code in real C and then compile with your MIPS C compiler using the argument to leave the .asm file. I think there is another argument to leave the C code as comments too. This would be really helpful to you. It is also a  good starting point for any future development.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the info. I think I can make it work by storing  one of the values in $t0 then subtracting from $t0 and storing the new value back into t0 like: li $t0, 2147483647                                   :                            subu $t0, $t0, 2147483648

Comment: Maybe, but that's not what a C compiler would do. It would realize that the expression can be evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: FYI, C doesn't have a stack pointer; we cannot ask C what is the value of the stack pointer.

Comment: Also, you have two separate questions arguably unrelated except by MIPS.  These would preferably be separate posts.  If you ask unrelated questions in the same question post, it will be vulnerable to being closed based on requiring more focus.

Answer (score 0):

> `sub $sp, $sp, 16`. Are there any additional steps with sp or am I simply subtracting 16 from $sp and storing the new value back in $sp?

What this does is subtract 16 from `sp`. This makes room for 4 words on the stack. MIPS doesn't put the return address on the stack, so you don't technically need to `addi $sp,$sp,16` to safely return, but it's recommended.

> My answer is subu $t0, 2147483647, 2147483648.

There's an easier way to do that:

```
li $t0,0
subiu $t0,1
```

This takes advantage of the 32-bit wraparound. This is actually fine, it's usually *signed overflow* that causes an exception.

Comment: `li` with `0` is pointless, you can `addiu $t0, $zero, -1` instead of materializing a zero in another register.  But you're not actually doing `2147483647u - 2147483648u` in that case, you're doing a different subtraction that has the same result.  Also not sure what you're trying to say with "*usually signed overflow that causes an exception.*" MIPS `addi` / `add`/`sub` always trap on signed overflow, never on wrapping between 0 and UINT_MAX (aka -1).  But `addiu` / `addu` / `subu` never trap, including on `(unsigned)INT_MAX - (unsigned)INT_MIN`.  (`subiu` only exists as a pseudo-instruction)

Comment: I figured the assembler optimized ```0``` into ```$zero``` but I didn't actually check. And you're right, "usually" wasn't the correct phrase to use there.

Comment: An assembler is never going to optimize away an instruction.  Classic MIPS assemblers would reordering instructions to fill the branch delay slot, but I don't think they'd do more than analyze dependencies and reorder.  If you want to optimize 2 steps down to one, you need a compiler.  If you write more asm instructions than necessary, it could have been for alignment reasons, or because you might do a computed jump to any instruction boundary.  It's up to you to optimize your assembly.

Comment: Not even ARM assembly with ```LDR r1,=Value```? I thought that was an optimization essentially, where if ```Value``` is 8-bit rotatable the instruction is changed into a ```MOV r1, Value``` and placed nearby as a data block if not.

Comment: `ldr r1, =value` isn't 2 instructions to start with; it's just one pseudo-instruction that some assemblers will expand to a mov-immediate.  (Or a PC-relative `ldr`, so it's actually always 1 instruction, just a question of whether space is needed in a literal pool nearby.  Unless some assemblers would consider expanding it to movw/movk.)  Similarly for MIPS, `li $t0, 0x12345678` will expand to 2 instructions, `li $t0, 0xffffffff` will expand to 1.  But an assembler will never *collapse* `li reg,0` / `add reg,-1` to `add reg, $zero, -1`

Comment: "so you don't technically need to addi $sp,$sp,16 to safely return" -- this is poor advice.  If a function allocates stack space, it must return the stack pointer to the value it was upon entry, even if it can get back to the caller without doing that, as failing to return the stack to where it was will have messed up the call stack, which is critical to most functions that allocate a stack frame (i.e. callers).